# silktest 20.5 + Windows 11: Anyone facing Issue executing Desktop.TypeKeys

Tags: windows-11, silktest

I am having Issues executing Desktop.Typekeys on windows11. I’m using the Silktest 20.5
Silktest hangs when it tries to execute Generic statement like Desktop.TypKeys.
Anyone facing the same Issue? Appreciate any workaround.